# How to do all the programming within a single folder in AVRDUDE?

Tags: bash, avrdude

I have this code

```
#!/bin/bash 
MEEP="$(pwd)"
cd $MEEP 
$MEEP/avrdude -C $MEEP/avrdude.conf -patmega32u4 -cstk500v2 -Pusb -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0xcb:m -Uhfuse:w:0xd8:m -Ulfuse:w:0xff:m
$MEEP/avrdude -C $MEEP/avrdude.conf -patmega32u4 -cstk500v2 -Pusb -Uflash:w:$MEEP/dosketch.cpp.hex:i -Ulock:w:0x2F:m
```

As you can see the avrdude avrdude.conf the hex file and the command file are all in one folder. Basically want I want to do is to do all the programming within a single folder. I first tried the "./avrdude" to signify that it was in the root folder but that still have me the error below which is

```
/Users/Demon/Desktop/MEEP/prog_tecla.command: line 5: /Users/Laura/avrdude: No such file or directory
/Users/Demon/Desktop/MEEP/prog_tecla.command: line 7: /Users/Laura/avrdude: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What i recieve on the terminal is this:/Users/Demon/Desktop/MEEP/prog_tecla.command: line 7: /Users/Demon/avrdude: No such file or directory

Comment: The problem here is that the files are all into one folder /USERS/DEMON/DESKTOP/MEEP but when I execute the command it looks for avrdude under /USERS/DEMON/avrdude

Comment: Naively, I'd say just replace $MEEP in the two command lines with the actual location of avrdude. Still get the value of $MEEP from "$(pwd)" and still use `cd $MEEP`, just don't use it in lines 4 and 5 of your bash script. Use usr/bin or whereever it is. `locate` is a command that will find it for you if you ask it nicely enough. :)

Comment: You're doing `MEEP="$(pwd)"; cd $MEEP`.  That effectively does nothing, it's a `cd` to the current directory.

Comment: (Not related to this question) @AustinPhillips: Well, in some case, it does make sense. from Terminal1, `cd /path/some/dir`. From term2, `rm -rf /path/some/dir; mv /path/some/other_dir /path/some/dir`. Then from term1, doing `cd $(pwd)`makes sense. `cd` & `pwd` work on path & not inode basis. Whereas the directory contents are listed inode based. I do it typically, when I mess up with some files in CWD & have to get them from a clean copy of current directory...